# Angular, consuming Observables with BehaviorSubject issues

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services, behaviorsubject

I've created a mess of code trying to sort out the actual way to properly consume shared data.

I have a service which is consuming data from other services, and returning a calculated interface.
(IDriverProfile)

The challenge I am facing, is that I want to consume all services at once. I originally used forkJoin for this and that worked great. The moment I tried changing the data to pull from a BehaviorSubject as an Observable things broke.

I'm fairly sure I'm doing something wrong with the combineLatest but is there some better way to approach this? This seems like a fairly basic use case:

1. Query services for filtered data
2. Mutate data based on some shared data set
3. Combine into a consumable object
4. Component consumes DriverProfileService

**DriverProfile.Service.ts** (Attempt 1)

Fails due to forkJoin not completing from behaviorSubject.

```ts
 getDriverProfile(data:IDriverData): Observable<IDriverProfile>{
    let driverStandings:IDriverStanding[] = [];
    let driverQualifying:IQualifying[] = [];
    let driverResults:IResult[] = [];
    let careerStats:IDriverCareerStats;   
    let SeasonData:IDriverSeasonData[]=[];
    
    let profile:IDriverProfile = {
      driverData: data,
      seasonsData: SeasonData,
      careerStats: careerStats
    };    

  // start forkJoin (works if all observables not utilizing shared data)  
    forkJoin({
      QualyTask: this.qualifyService.getDriverQualifyingLaps(data.driver),
      StandingsTask: this.driverStandingsService.getDriverStandings(data.driver),
      ResultsTask: this.resultService.getDriverResults(data.driver),
      RaceTask: this.raceService.getAllRaces(),
      statusTask: this.statusService.status$,
      teamsTask: this.teamsService.getAllConstructors()
    }).subscribe(({QualyTask, StandingsTask, ResultsTask, RaceTask, statusTask, teamsTask})=>{
      driverQualifying = QualyTask;      
      driverStandings = StandingsTask;
      driverResults = ResultsTask;    
      let races = RaceTask; 
      let allStatus = statusTask;
      let teams = teamsTask;
      console.log('all status',allStatus);

      let results = this.getResults(driverResults, races, driverStandings, allStatus, teams);
      //console.log("results", results);
      // calc career stats
      profile.seasonsData = results.seasons;
      profile.careerStats = results.stats;
    });    
    console.log("profile", profile);
    

    return of(profile);
  }
```

**DriverProfile.Service.ts** (Attempt 2 CombineLatest)

Not sure why this fails?

```ts
 getDriverProfile(data:IDriverData): Observable<IDriverProfile>{
    
// this section is for trying combineLatest (broken)
    let task1 = this.qualifyService.getDriverQualifyingLaps(data.driver);
    let task2 = this.driverStandingsService.getDriverStandings(data.driver);
    let task3 = this.resultService.getDriverResults(data.driver);
    let task4 = this.raceService.getAllRaces();
    let task5 = this.statusService.status$;
    let task6 = this.teamsService.getAllConstructors();
    const combine$ = combineLatest(task1, task2, task3, task4, task5, task6,
      (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6)=> {
        let results = this.getResults(t3, t4, t2, t5, t6);
        return <IDriverProfile> {
          driverData: data,
          seasonsData: results.seasons,
          careerStats: results.stats
        }
      });  

    return combine$;
  }
```

**Status.Service.ts**

```ts
private readonly _StatusSource = new BehaviorSubject<IStatus[]>([]);

  readonly status$ = this._StatusSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { 
    this.loadInitialData();
  }

  loadInitialData() {
    this.httpClient.get<IStatus[]>("assets/data/status.json").subscribe(x => {
      //console.log('status load', x);
      this._setStatus(x);
    },
    err => console.log("Error loading Status")
    );
  }

  getStatus(): IStatus[] {
    return this._StatusSource.getValue();
  }

  private _setStatus(status: IStatus[]): void {
    this._StatusSource.next(status);
    this._StatusSource.complete();
  }
```

Comment: I started reading this, but stopped after I got a headache. This isn’t that much code, I suggest planning out what you want, and how you need to consume it and then rewriting this. It super unclear why you are using both combine latest and forkJoin, and seemingly doing the same API calls twice.

Comment: I can clear that up, I was just trying to include both sets of code that I tried.
First I tried the forkJoin, then secondly I tried to to a combineLatest. Both which don't return the results I want.

ForkJoin doesn't execute because of the behaviorSubject.
the CombineLatest doesn't seem to work either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getDriverProfile` method I assume is being subscribed to in one of your components as you mention step 4: "Component consumes DriverProfileService".

**DriverProfile.Service.ts** update the method to below:

```ts
// Assuming everything within the combine latest call are observables. 

 getDriverProfile(data:IDriverData): Observable<IDriverProfile> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(
        this.qualifyService.getDriverQualifyingLaps(data.driver),
        this.driverStandingsService.getDriverStandings(data.driver),
        this.resultService.getDriverResults(data.driver),
        this.raceService.getAllRaces(),
        this.statusService.getStatusSource(),
        this.teamsService.getAllConstructors()
    ).map((t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6) => {

        // I assume getResults is not an observable, it just transforms data or something.
        let results = this.getResults(t3, t4, t2, t5, t6);

        return <IDriverProfile> {
          driverData: data,
          seasonsData: results.seasons,
          careerStats: results.stats
        } 
    });
  }
```

As for your **Status.Service.ts** lets keep it simple:

```ts
// Declare your subject and set value to empty array
private statusSource = new BehaviorSubject<IStatus[]>([]);

// Contructor calling the method to get data initially
constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { 
    this.loadInitialData();
}

loadInitialData() {
    this.httpClient.get<IStatus[]>("assets/data/status.json")
    .subscribe(statusSource => {
        this.setStatusSource(statusSource);
    },(error) => console.log(error));
}

// Gets the status source
getStatusSource(): Observable<IStatus[]> {
    return this.statusSource.asObservable();
}

// Sets the status source
public setStatusSource(statusSource: IStatus[]): void {
    this.statusSource.next(statusSource);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me to where I was going. Cheers!